# Seam and JSF: How to post multiple values instead of single

Tags: jsf, seam, facelets

We have this ui:repeat:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{notAssigned}" var="pair">
   #{pair.data.processName}<br/>
   <s:button value="assign" action="#{mypage.assign}">
        <f:param name="taskId" value="#{pair.task.id}"/>
   </s:button>
</ui:repeat>
```

Now I can assign one and one elements but pushing the assign button. But I want to refactor this and add a checkbox, so that you can choose all that you want to assign, and then push one button that will assign all.

How can I modify this code to support `checkbox` that contains the `taskId` (which is a Long) and one  button to submit.

**UPDATE**

I tried changing the code to use `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{mypage.notAssignedTaskIds}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{pair.task.id}" itemLabel="#{messages['choose']}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
#{pair.data.processName}


<h:commandButton action="#{mypage.test}" value="Assign"/>
```

And in my bean:

```
@Setter @Getter
List<String> notAssignedTaskIds = new ArrayList<String>();

public void test() {
    log.info("Inside test, size of list #0", notAssignedTaskIds.size());
    for(String id : notAssignedTaskIds) {
        log.info("TaskId's chosen #0", id);
    }
}
```

But notAssignedTaskids is always empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is, create a boolean flag in pair object. Then

```
<a:region>

    <ui:repeat value="#{notAssigned}" var="pair">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{pair.booleanFlag}">

        #{pair.data.processName}
    </ui:repeat>

    <a:commandLink action="#{yourBean.assignAll()}" value="assignAll">
    </a:commandLink>

</a:region>
```

In your bean, iterate over notAssigned list.

```
public void assignAll() {
.
.
.
    for (Pair pair : notAssigned) {
        if (pair.booleanFlag) {
            mypage.assign(pair);
        }
    }


}
```

And modify your assign method to get a pair object. By the way you can do it without ajax support. Just remove
region and convert your a:commandLink to h:commandLink.

Comment: Hi. This is certainly plausible, but I would like to do it in another way instead of this "hack"

Comment: +1: I can confirm that this worked. However, I still would like to have another solution if possible

Comment: It should work with notassignedtaskid list also. Your manycheckbox is in a form, isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to alter your model, then add a `Map<Long, Boolean>` to your bean.

```
private Map<Long, Boolean> selectedIds = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();
```

Bind it to `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` value with task ID as key.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.notAssigned}" var="pair">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbok value="#{bean.selectedIds[pair.task.id]}" />
    #{pair.data.processName}
</ui:repeat>
<s:button value="assign" action="#{bean.assign}" />
```

Collect the selected values in `assign()` method.

```
List<Pair> selectedPairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
for (Pair pair : notAssigned) {
    if (selectedIds.get(pair.getTask().getId())) {
        selectedPairs.add(pair);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you want a h:selectManyCheckbox element. Check out the docs [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectManyCheckbox.html).